# How to allow Apache PUT method to directory

Tags: apache-2.4, http

I would like to enable Apache 2.4.7 to allow PUT to specific directory. Config below gives 405 error code in access log after PUT request.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log common

  <Directory /var/www/default/put>
    <Limit PUT>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Limit>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```